# Still Dismissing Alert

Tags: objective-c, ipad, delegates, uialertview

I am trying to keep this `UIAlertView` up after the presses either of the buttons (1 & 2).

Once i click on the "+" button or the "-" button, I can see the `UILabel` text increment, then it closes the `UIAlertView`.

This is what i currently am using:

```
#pragma Alert View Methods

-(void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
{
        [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:animated];

}

#pragma count functions
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1 || buttonIndex == 2) {
        return;
    }
    else{

        [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        self.currentCountButtonCount++;
        [self.countAlert setMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.countButtonCount + 1]];

    }if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        self.currentCountButtonCount--;
        [self.countAlert setMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.countButtonCount - 1]];

    }
}

- (IBAction)countClick:(id)sender {


    // tallies and keeps current count number

    if (!self.currentCountButtonCount)
         self.currentCountButtonCount = 0;

   NSString *alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.countButtonCount];

    self.countAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Count" message:alertMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"end" otherButtonTitles:@"+",@"-", nil];

   [self.countAlert show];
}
```

On my last question someone told me to do it custom and this is what im trying now and it still dismisses the UIAlert.

How can i keep it up while the label changes until they touch the end button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you using is default button of AlertView and after click on that button it will automatically dismissed the alertview.

So you have to create your buttons programatically and add that buttons in your alertview like:

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[btn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[countAlert addSubview:btn ];
```

on this btn call your method.

So you have to create two custom button with "+" and "-". and add that buttons in AlertView.

```
-(void)setAlertValue:(id)sender{

    switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 1:
        {
           // currentCountButtonCount++;

            [self.countAlert setMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",++countButtonCount]];
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            //currentCountButtonCount--;

            [self.countAlert setMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",--countButtonCount]];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)countClick:(id)sender {
// tallies and keeps current count number

    if (!currentCountButtonCount)
        currentCountButtonCount = 0;

    NSString *alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", countButtonCount];

    self.countAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Count" message:alertMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"end" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];


    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 40, 20)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(setAlertValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    btn.tag = 1;

    [btn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIButton *btn1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 50, 40, 20)];
    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(setAlertValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    btn1.tag = 2;

    [btn1 setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [countAlert addSubview:btn];
    [countAlert addSubview:btn1];
    [self.countAlert show];

}
```

[image]

Comment: What method would i overwrite for that? @BaZinga

Comment: you shouldn't overwrite alert at all.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me get the right look and feel i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to rain in your parade, but if you think that an alert view is the best way to handle an increment/decrement of a variable, I would suggest you to reconsider your design.

UIAlertViews are meant for transient information and simplified decision making. A simple "Are you sure?" is the text-book example of an alert view usage.

From the user stand point, it's much more comforting being able to modify all the attributes in sliders or any other form of permanent input, and then, when sure, hit the confirm button with an alert view (or confirmation screen). Doing it in an Alert view is not only error prone, but counter-intuitive compared in the way that the rest of iOS works.

If you're having trouble on fitting another form of input in your application, please read on how to perform animations and reveal control as they are needed, hiding the input inside an UIAlertView is simply the easiest solution for you, but not the best for the user.